# Does QGIS support MT83F

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Does QGIS support NAD83 Montana State Plane Zone, US Foot?
I have vector data in a CSV file that I would like to display, but the coordinate system is MT83F.  I don't see a matching CRS.  Is there a user defined CRS that is appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS has a CRS for NAD83 Montana State Plane Zone (ft), it's EPSG:2256.
good for searching epsg codes here...
[Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/)

Comment: Thanks Brad.  That was very helpful.  I Tried searching for Montana in QGIS CRS selector but it did not find a match for some reason.

Comment: @SeanL you probably need to set 'Search within' to search for names not IDs in the CRS selection box.